# Restore Gnome Bookmarks with passwords

Tags: gnome, keyrings

I have a bunch of bookmarks in my laptop, I know I can copy ~/.gtk-bookmarks to my desktop

But i have to re-entry all the passwords for ftp, ssh, etc...

Is there a way i could restore the bookmarks **along** with theirs respective passwords.

My username/id is the same in both computers and both keyrings are unlocked on login.

Any help?

Comment: I think one is supposed to be able to use Gnome Keyring to handle all of those but after spending the better part of an afternoon trying to get it working, gave up. What documentation exists is limited, contradictory, and sometimes mutually exclusive. Having Gnome, GnuPG and SSH all laying claim to the same facility doesn't much help. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restore a backup of my keyring (containing ssh key passprases, nautilus remote filesystem passwords and wifi passwords)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/212299/how-do-i-restore-a-backup-of-my-keyring-containing-ssh-key-passprases-nautilus)

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are stored in the Gnome Keyring with no technical connection to bookmarks. Try copying `~/.gnome2/keyrings` from your old home directory to restore the entire keyring.

You can use Accessories -> Passwords and Encryption Keys afterwards to clean up any old passwords you don't use anymore.

Comment: I did this, but have no luck. I guess I could backup and restore the keyrings only in the same machine. Even when i could see the passwords in Gnome Keyring, nautilus kept asking me for passwords to open the bookmarks