# Using keyring restored from other system

Tags: password, migration, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore Gnome Bookmarks with passwords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3879/restore-gnome-bookmarks-with-passwords)

I have recently had a severe hard disk failure and so had to rescue my keyring(`/home/username/.gnome2/keyrings`) from the failed disk. How should I go about copying said data to a new installation with the same password, but on a different disk(It is a fresh installation, not a copy). Will I need to somehow load the keyring in a different manner, or may I just copy said directory and operate upon it as normal? Again, the source and target are identical in version(Precise/12.04), architecture(both amd64), and they have the same password.